# Изменение языковых параметров DictationRecognizer Unity

Tags: unity3d

DictationRecognizer в Unity распознает слова английской грамматики  -можно ли как нибудь распознавать русский или вообще любой другой язык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DictationRecognizer из юнити использует систему распознавания голоса из Windows 10. Т.е. эта фукнция будет доступна только на этой системе и только, если распознавание разрешено в настройках Windows.
[Подробнее из документации Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.DictationRecognizer.html)
[Подробнее из документации Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17208/windows-10-use-speech-recognition)
В документации распознователя Windows указано, что:

> Speech Recognition is only available for the following languages:
>   English (United States, United Kingdom, Canada, India, and Australia),
>   French, German, Japanese, Mandarin (Chinese Simplified and Chinese
>   Traditional), and Spanish.

т.е. он распознаёт пока только английский (США, Британия, Канада, Индия, Австралия), французский, немецкий, японский, китайский и испанский.